# Can we share PDF or other documents using JSQMessanger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

We want to share PDF or other documents using JSQMessanger. Because we have used JSQMessanger for chating in our App.

Answer (score 0):

You should expand JSQ functionalities for the PDF source

Comment: Which type of JSQ functionalities?

Comment: Reseach JSQ library, and add this func inside

Answer (score 0):

Look at how the example app does media items i.e. Video or images. It will be similar to this and then you just need to adapt it so that it can handle the PDF payload. Definitely a great thing to add to the library.